# Is there any way to update css on paypal payment method page in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2, payment-method

[image: I want to update this page but it's css is loading from paypal website. common.css is loading from paypal website,still no changes are getting reflected]

I want to update this page but it's css is loading from paypal website. common.css is loading from paypal website,still no changes are getting reflected

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to tweak CSS components using jQuery the way it was done in M1 - that will no longer work in M2, since M2 uses RequireJS.

Instead, you should add something like this in your desired PHTML file:

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery"
        ], function ($) {
                // Perform desired action(s) on the selector(s) you're interested in
                // For example:
                $("#UiElementOfInterest").hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Hope that helps! :)